# CSS3 columns layout on click issue

Tags: html, css

I have this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5yjsjnjj/1/) and it works fine, however when I click on any of the last li of each columns it seems like it pushes the paragraph down. I can't figure out why....

```
.columns-3 {
-webkit-column-count: 3;
-moz-column-count: 3;
-o-column-count: 3;
column-count: 3;
}

.column-layout {
list-style-type: none;
margin: .9rem 0 0 0;
}
```

Comment: When I remove the link the issue disappears...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this seems to be a issue with chrome, if you inspect the link and change the state to `:focus` the link receives a blue box `outline: -webkit-focus-ring-color auto 5px;`, which basically pushes away the `<p>`

To bypass this add this:

```
a:focus{
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure? `outline` doesn't effect an elements dimensions

Comment: They jump around in your fiddle too. Like I said `outline` doesn't effect an elements dimensions in any way so it can't be the cause.

Comment: I know outline does not affect dimensions but for some weird reason it does that in Chrome, in my fiddle the left one does not jump and the right does, for demonstration purposes. Note I forgote to change the cols, here the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5yjsjnjj/6/

Answer (score 0):

Helo Alex

http://jsfiddle.net/tayyab_rashid/5yjsjnjj/4/

CSS UPdated

```
.columns-3 {
-webkit-column-count: 3;
-moz-column-count: 3;
-o-column-count: 3;
column-count: 3;
    display:table;
}

.column-layout {
list-style-type: none;
    display:table-cell;
margin: .9rem 0 0 0;
}
```

here is the fiddle i have updated you just need to add display property to your list then bottom paragraph wont jump.

Comment: It does still jump in your fiddle, also in firefox the columns get lost.

Comment: is it possible for you to give it minimum height to ul ??